# i can't run tg-admin in python2.7, how can i do that?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-11.04, turbogears, turbogears2

I was trying to run tg-admin in ubuntu 11.04 on python 2.7 but I keep having an error shown below, but later I was able to run it using python 2.6 like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'TurboGears==1.1.1','console_scripts','tg-admin'
__requires__ = 'TurboGears==1.1.1'
```

I changed the first line to :

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
```

and it works fine, but since the default python version on ubuntu11.04 is python 2.7 so it keeps failing when I try to run some thing with it, and the error message is like this :

.......bla...bla and @ last

```
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/peak/util/assembler.py", line 221, in TryExcept
  next_test.JUMP_IF_FALSE, Code.POP_TOP,      # remove condition
  AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'JUMP_IF_FALSE'
```

Comment: Got the same problem ;-(